# Azure Automation: Runbook: Get all AAD Group Properties, e.g. the Notes / Info field?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-runbook

Good afternoon

I have selected stackoverflow for this question because probably mainly programmers are confronted with this question:

#### This is the issue:

- We want to read the notes field (not the description) from the Azure AD groups
- Contrary to what we might expect (and what the command names suggests), most commands in Microsofts PowerShell Modules to Access the Azure AD do not return an Azure AD Object, but only a small subset of its properties.
- For example, both `Get-AzADGroup` and `Get-AzureADGroup` are only half-heartedly implemented and don't offer a solution to get all properties. The Microsoft "Docs" ignores this basic subject.

#### Therefore the Question:

Can a Runbook read all Azure AD Group Properties (or at least the Notes field)? In OnPremise AD, this property is called `.Info`

Thanks a lot for any help!

Kind regards, 
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

According to some test, the command `Get-AzADGroup` and `Get-AzureADGroup` will not show the field `Notes` or `Info` even if add `| fl` after the command. And it seems the `Notes(Info)` field is not synced to cloud for groups. Here I found a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36959512-ad-attribute-info-aka-notes-for-groups-should-be) which similar to your situation, you can vote it on this page or raise a new feedback ticket for your requirements.